# How to build and define two python servers in docker compose

Tags: python, docker-compose

I am trying to send an array of double periodically from one python service to another. The first one works on collecting the array of doubles from a sensor. The second should do some mathematical calculation on this collected data. How can I build the interface of these two servers in docker-compose and how can I periodically send this data from one server to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  receiver:
    image: receiver_app
    container_name: receiver
    links:
    - calculator

  calculator:
    image: calculator_app
    container_name: calculator
```

Using the word 'links' allows you to send and receive network traffic between containers. You may set this variable like this: `calc:calculator`. Now the container `calculator` is reachable from `receiver` at the hostnames `calc` and `calculator`.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links

In Python you must create new network connection and send the data.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. In this project I need to define two python build on images one for receiver and other for calculator. for each I should define a Dockerfile. how can I manage that? should I place every service in its own file and mention the directory in the docker-compose file?

Comment: Thanks I have got the answer of my question, we can just mention the name of our dockerfile in the docker-compose.yml file (ex:`build: .                 
                                                                           dockerfile: Dockerfile-engine`)

Comment: Yes that's right. You can use this parameter specifying the directory where the Dockerfile is located. This can be the current directory.